# What are the additional books in the Contemporary English Version?

Tags: revelation, versification, apocrypha

I was reading about the Contemporary English Version (CEVDC) Revelation 12 and came across this passage that is not found in NIV or KJV:

The dragon stood on the beach beside the sea.
[Revelation 12:18 CEVDC](https://bible.com/bible/303/rev.12.18.CEVDC)

There are other examples but too many to list. Upon closer examination, there are many other **books** as well, e.g.

- Bel and the dragon
- Baruch
- Susanna... etc.

Where do all these 'additional' resources come from? How are they received by scholars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The versification of the Bible is not inspired, and there are occasionally different ways of breaking up the text into chapters and verses. You can compare [many translations here](https://biblehub.com/revelation/12-17.htm).

The CEV is taking one option, and making the sentence "The dragon stood on the beach beside the sea." as a distinct verse. This is also the option taken by the NLT, CSB, GNT, ISV, and more.

Another option is to leave that sentence as part of verse 17, as the ESV and NET do.

Another option is to make that sentence be part of Rev 13:1, as the NIV and NASB do.

Finally, the KJV translates it as "And I stood upon the sand of the sea", again putting it in Rev 13:1. The KJV has first person rather than third person because its source text has a different word. See [this question for more details](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/8261/2757).

The books of Bel and the Dragon, Baruch, etc are part of the [Apocrypha or Deuterocanon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterocanonical_books).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Silly me I thought the added text came from another some other sources.